# How to use the javascript SDK from a desktop application

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, oauth, desktop

I'm writing a desktop application to interact with facebook by using an embedded browser which is running HTML \ javascript from local files.

I was able to use the login dialog to retrieve a token (using the method described in the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) for desktop applications), but i'm still failing call basic SDK functions, such as *FB.init()* and *FB.getLoginStatus()*.

When executing *FB.init()*:

```
    FB.init({
        appId: '120260327220',
        status: true, // check login status
        oauth: true // enable OAuth 2.0
    });
```

I get the HTTP response (through HTTP sniffer):

```
<span>Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the Application configuration. It must match one of the Connect or Canvas URLs or domain must be the same as or a subdomain of one of the Application&#039;s base domains.</span>
```

And when executing *FB.getLoginStatus()*:

```
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                alert("logged in and connected user, someone you know");
            } else {
                alert("no user session available, someone you dont know");
            }
        });
```

i get nothing!

The application is completely client based, meaning i have no server side, thus there's no URL to register the facebook application with. Running on IE.

Does anyone know if and how i can use the facebook javascript SDK from a local javascript file (for desktop application)?

**EDIT:** configuring the application URL to be http://localhost is not a valid option, since eventually this script should be able to run on any machine, whether localhost is configured or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Why does `http://localhost` not work for you? You have to configure your **app** to accept `http://localhost`, once configured it works on every PC.

Comment: Max - I don't want to get into configuring localhost on my end users' PCs. I'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related:

> The JS SDK is designed to be used on websites (per definition served and accessible over http or https) and we do not plan to support the use of file: or any other protocols.
>   This is consistent with plugins in general, where http/https URIs are usable as identifiers (open graph amongst others), but where file:// URIs are not.
>
> You can try initializing the SDK inside a web accessible document including using an iframe - note then that you will have to add logic to ensure correct resizing.

As an answer to a [Facebook bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165982843535513/).

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you have an embedded browser within your Desktop app so in this case what you can do is host the app's page that has facebook related functionality over the web and pull this same page's url inside your embedded browser. This way you will be able to provide a valid domain in app's settings and not localhost. Also you can make valid calls to facebook APIs from your page and your Desktop app can then make use of all these facebook related data as they are being pulled onto your embedded browser.

In a nutshell your Desktop app will be much like the Facebook's canvas where the app's page is pulled and displayed inside the canvas. However in your case you will be having a complete control of how, when, where and which parts of the page gets displayed and moreover a properly glued and well structured UI will make the external page and Desktop app blend together and users will never come to know the difference.

Comment: Thanks, but uploading the page is not an option

Answer (score 1):

Since I got no acceptable answer here are my realizations and what I eneded up doing::

There's no way to use the Facebook SDK on local page due to cross domain ajax issues.

The way to work around it is using JSONP ajax calls to Facebook's graph API (JSONP is allowed for cross domain).
The login process is done by navigation (in a new window) to the login page, with specific URL parameters to set the page's attributes.

Comment: @user1692342, unfortunately the only example I have is from 3 years ago, which no longer works. The API had changed drastically since then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PhoneGap 1.0 and Xcode 4, start  by following these instructions: http://www.pushittolive.com/post/1239874936/facebook-login-on-iphone-phonegap

My installation looks like: http://cl.ly/AHQ1

Be sure to move the ChildBrowser.js file out of the plugins folder and into the root of your www folder. Also be sure to link to that ChildBrowser.js in your index.html file.

Then follow these 3 steps, http://collingo.com/2011/08/18/installing-childbrowser-ios-phonegap-plugin-in-xcode-4/

Lastly, update your PhoneGap.plist file as mentioned in this post: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/43708792/How%20to%20Install%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS, mine looks like: http://cl.ly/AHAH

Comment: thanks, but i'm not developing a phone app. i develop for windows, using IE. though a authentication mentioned in the first link is what i do to log in. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Application URL that you have set on the application's Developer page? I'm just guessing based on the FB.init() error message that you need the to set the URL to be "http://localhost/start page name". When debugging our application we run it locally and have the URL of the application set this way.

Comment: thanks, but configuring the app URL to be localhost is not a valid option for me. eventually the script should be able to run locally on any windows machine, either localhost is configured or not...

Comment: Missed the part that you were running as a desktop application. In that case you don't have a canvas URL.