# Facebook JS SDK display:page is not working

Tags: c++, facebook, winapi, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to open **Facebook's oauth** dialog in same web page.

Actually, I have embedded an static html page in my WIN32 (C++) project and I am using Facebooks's **JS  SDK** to perform **oauth** operation as IE cannot afford url length longer than 2K (approx).

Display option **popup** & **touch** is working fine but option **page** & **iframe** is not working.

Here is the code;

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '*************', // App ID
    channelUrl : 'file:///D:/channel.htm', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'oauth',
        name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
        link: 'http://localhost',
        picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
        caption: 'Reference Documentation',
        description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
        display: 'page'
    },
     function(response) {

        if (response && response.post_id) {
          //alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
          //alert('Post was not published.');
        }
      }
    );
  };
</script>
```

Please could any one tell me that what am I missing in above code to open oauth dialog in same web page.

Thanks,
SKAR.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered [a similar problem in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471871/how-to-use-the-javascript-sdk-from-a-desktop-application).

Here's the answer I got:

> The JS SDK is designed to be used on websites (per definition served and accessible over http or https) and we do not plan to support the use of file: or any other protocols.
>   This is consistent with plugins in general, where http/https URIs are usable as identifiers (open graph amongst others), but where file:// URIs are not.
>
> You can try initializing the SDK inside a web accessible document including using an iframe - note then that you will have to add logic to ensure correct resizing.

As an answer to a [Facebook bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165982843535513/).